# Performance of switch within a loop

Tags: c++, performance, g++

We have a map of message types to a list of messages. Given a performance critical piece of code such as this:

```
struct row_t {
    int message_type; //0,1,2,3,4,5
};
map<int, vector<row_t>> message_map;

for (auto x : message_map) {
    int message_type = x.first;
    vector<row_t> message_rows = x.second;

    for (row_t row : message_rows) {
        //LARGE CODE CHUNK
        switch(row.message_type) { //same as switch(message_type)
            case 0:
                add_0_to_database();
                break;
            case 1:
                add_0_to_database();
                break;
            //...
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The switch statement will execute on every iteration of the inner loop, even though every single element in message_rows has the same type.

This problem can be eliminated to only run switch statement once before inner loop starts:

```
for (auto x : message_map) {
    int message_type = x.first;
    vector<row_t> message_rows = x.second;

    switch(message_type) {
        case 0:
            for (row_t row : message_rows) {
                //LARGE CODE CHUNK
                add_0_to_database(row);
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            for (row_t row : message_rows) {
                //LARGE CODE CHUNK
                add_1_to_database(row);
            }
            break;
        //...
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

But now we have multiple redundant inner loops and "LARGE CODE CHUNK" code needs to be duplicated several times.

My question: can modern compilers (specifically g++) optimize version 1 to be as efficient as version 2?

Or should I go with version 2, and perhaps consider using some other method to remove redundancy, such as setting function pointer to `add_{0/1}_to_database` in switch statement and then using the function pointer in the loop?

Comment: Since you don't seem to *need* `x` to be a copy, you should change `for (auto x : message_map)` to `for (const auto& x : message_map)` - depending on how expensive the types in `message_map` are to copy, that may give you a small speed boost.

Comment: "My question: can modern compilers (specifically g++) optimize version 1 to be as efficient as version 2?" - why don't you just check? Compile the two versions at different optimization levels and look at the generated code + time their execution.

Comment: Just leave it like the first version which is much easier to maintain.  The time used in the switch will be small compared to the performance variation of the `LARGE CODE CHUNK`.  If you've profiled this and it is _really_ a problem, you can go the function pointer route but that may not gain much (if anything).

Comment: The compiler surely cannot transform the first code snippet into the second, because it does not know that `row.message_type == x.first`.  However if you `switch` based on `x.first` which doesn't change inside the loop, then the optimizer may perform loop interchange.

Comment: (That's completely apart from the fact that in the first snippet, `case 1:` calls `add_0_to_database()` and the second snippet calls `add_1_to_database()` under the same conditions)

Comment: Thank you all for advise. I was using references already, but removed them in sample code for simplicity. The performance difference with switch/loop was negligent. I decided to remove the map and put all messages into the same vector to simplify the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably your real `row_t` is more complicated than is shown in the question. If it isn't, there's no need to loop over the vector. Simply use the length.

As is always the case with performance issues, the first thing to do is test. There's no need to worry if this part of your code base isn't performance-critical. Make your code clean and simple. The rest of this answer assumes testing reveals that this is indeed a performance bottleneck. I'll first address two items that might well be much larger performance issues before I get to a solution.

1. Use of a `std::map`. Traversing an ordered map can be expensive. Consider switching to a `std::unordered_map`, which were introduced in c++11. Your use of a range-based loop indicates you are using c++11 or later.
2. Excessive copying. The outer loop `for (auto x : message_map)` makes a copy, as do `vector<row_t> message_rows = x.second` and `for (row_t row : message_rows)`. You are copying the vector twice, plus an additional copy of each element. Use references.

A solution: Consider using a function pointer. A simple approach is to move the switch statement out of the inner loop, but instead of having a loop as indicated in the question, set a function pointer:

```
for (auto& x : message_map) // Note the use of auto& to avoid copying.
{
    int message_type = x.first;
    std::vector<row_t>& message_rows = x.second; // Avoid copying!
    void (* add_to_database)(const row_t&) = nullptr;

    switch(message_type)
    {
    case 0:
        add_to_database = add_0_to_database;
        break;
    case 1:
        add_to_database = add_1_to_database;
        break;
    //...
    default:
        // This might be an error that should be handled here.
        break;
    }

    for (row_t& row : message_rows) // Avoid copying!
    {
        // LARGE CODE CHUNK
        add_to_database (row);
    }
}
```

That switch statement is a bit ugly. Version 2.0 converts this to another map:

```
typedef void (*AddFunction)(const row_t&);
std::unordered_map<int, AddFunction> add_function_map;

// Outside the loop, populate the map:
add_function_map[0] = add_0_to_database;
add_function_map[1] = add_1_to_database;
// Rest of add_function_map population elided.

// The loop is now short and sweet.
for (auto& x : message_map) // Note the use of auto& to avoid copying.
{
    int message_type = x.first;
    std::vector<row_t>& message_rows = x.second; // Avoid copying!
    AddFunction add_to_database = add_function_map[message_type];
    for (row_t& row : message_rows) // Avoid copying!
    {
        // LARGE CODE CHUNK
        add_to_database (row);
    }
}
```